# How to monitor a process that is running inside a container

Tags: docker, containers

I am new to Docker container and my question is how to monitor a process that is running inside a container. For Example, I have a container running apache in it. how would I know if apache process inside container got killed but my container is still running.

How we will ensure specific process inside the container is running,if that process goes down how we will get alert ?

Comment: do you want to monitor process at container level or monitor each process independently inside container?

Comment: I want to monitor the container level running process from outside container (i.e host level). Because i shouldn't face a scenario like my Container is running but the application process  inside  container is died.

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile reference has the answer:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

More specifically, the HEALTHCHECK directive:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Essentially, when your container's entrypoint fails, the container dies:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

But, in any case, a process running inside a container is also visible from the host's process list, so you can safely use the output of `ps aux| grep httpd` to monitor your apache's PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

In production , you don't just use docker run , you need to use some container orchestrator like kubernetes where you define the health checks such as liveness and readiness probes and the orchestrator will take care of the rest , it will restart the container if apache fails for some reason.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes